# Loadbalancing Websockets in to multiple containers

Tags: .net-core, websocket

I've been reading various posts on stack overflow and other sites related to this. but still confused.

Basically we have a service hosted in AWS ECS as a container, which has some REST end points. we are planning to convert them in to Sockets, and main problem I have is how do I manage the socket connection between multiple instances of the image when we scale up and use load balancers.

Would love some useful explanations or links related to this.

Comment: If you are using SignalR, this should be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/scale?view=aspnetcore-5.0 . Especially the section about using a redis backplane, which can be a concrete implementation of scaling signalr connections.

Comment: I’m not using signalR